# two or more forms in one view using one post request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have only two forms for the moment in my view, they are both post method I tried to solve it like this

route

```
Route::post('view', function(){
    if(Input::has('form1')){
        'NameController@method1';
    } elseif (Input::has('form2')){
       'NameController@method2';
    }
});
```

view

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/view')) !!}

    {!! Form::text('text', $trans->text)    !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', array('name' => 'form1' )) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}


{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/view')) !!}

    {!! Form::text('text', 'text')    !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', array('name' => 'form2')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And it throw's out this error

```
syntax error, unexpected ''ConfigurationController@title'    (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)
```

it was error in coding I corrected it but it won't do what I wish it simply returns blank screen it doesn't cycle trough controllers

I modified the code(removed return and closed the route)

Comment: There isn't in (routes.php) any string unclosed? like `'ConfigurationController@title`?

Comment: Please show full `routes.php`.

Comment: I added and explanation and correction

Comment: try adding `dd(Input::all());` just on the first line of the route, so you can see if its one, hitting the route and two, what info its then retuning

Comment: the both forms are sending data correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create a method `someMethodName` in the `NameController` and in there

```
public function someMethodName()
{
    if(Input::has('form1')){
        $this->method1();
    } elseif (Input::has('form2')){
        $this->method2();
    }
}
```

then replace all the route stuff with

```
Route::post('view', 'NameController@someMethodName')
```